# C# Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, accessibility

I get an inconsistent accessibility error when trying to compile my C# code. I have googled it extensively, but all the cases and answers I find deal with some private-public inconstancy. I have not written private ANYWHERE in my code at all, I have checked and double checked. I read something somewhere that I could try "lowering the scope", but I have no idea what that means. Help.

Sorry for missing code, here it is on github:
        https://gist.github.com/jyggorath/7589742

```
using System;

public class oblig5 {

    // // // BEGIN GLOBAL 1 // // //
    public const int STRLEN = 40;
    public const int MAXPERSONER = 500;
    public const int MAXLAG = 50;
    public enum funksjon {trener, oppman, ingen};
    // // // END GLOBAL 1 // // //

    // // // BEGIN PERSON CLASS // // //
    public class Person {
        // // // privates:
        public string navn;
        public string adr;
        public string mail;
        public string klasse;
        public int tlf;
        public funksjon verv;
        public int lagnr;

        // // // publics:
        // constructor
        public Person() {
            navn = ""; adr = ""; mail = ""; klasse = "";
            tlf = 0; lagnr = 0;
            verv = (funksjon)2;
        }

        // skriv:
        public void skriv() {
            Console.WriteLine("Navn: {0}\nAdresse: {1}\nMail: {2}\nKlasse: {3}\nTlf: {4}\nLagnr: {5}", navn, adr, mail, klasse, tlf, lagnr);
            if (verv == (funksjon)0)
                Console.WriteLine("Er Trener\n");
            else if (verv == (funksjon)1)
                Console.WriteLine("Er Oppmann\n");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Har ikkeno verv\n");
            lag[lagnr].skriv();
        }

        public void skriv2() {
            Console.WriteLine("Navn: {0}\nAdresse: {1}\nMail: {2}\nKlasse: {3}\nTlf: {4}\n", navn, adr, mail, klasse, tlf);
        }

        // les:
        public void les_data(int lnr) {
            lagnr = lnr;
            navn = les_str("Personens navn");
            adr = les_str("Personens adresse");
            mail = les_str("Personens mail");
            klasse = les_str("Hvilke klasse går personen i?");
            tlf = les_int("Personens telefonnr", 10000000, 99999999);
            verv = les_enum();
        }

        // fil:
        public void skriv_til_fil(System.IO.StreamWriter file) {
            file.WriteLine(navn);
            file.WriteLine(adr);
            file.WriteLine(mail);
            file.WriteLine(klasse);
            file.WriteLine(tlf);
            file.WriteLine((int)verv);
            file.WriteLine(lagnr);
        }

        public void les_fra_fil(System.IO.StreamReader file, string nvn) {
            navn = nvn;
            adr = file.ReadLine();
            mail = file.ReadLine();
            klasse = file.ReadLine();
            tlf = int.Parse(file.ReadLine());
            verv = (funksjon)int.Parse(file.ReadLine());
            lagnr = int.Parse(file.ReadLine());
        }

        // sammenligninger:
        public bool har_navn(string t) {
            return (navn == t);
        }

        public bool har_verv(funksjon v) {
            return (verv == v);
        }

        public bool tilhorer_lag(int n) {
            return (lagnr == n);
        }
    }
    // // // END PERSON CLASS // // //

    // // // BEGIN LAG CLASS // // //
    public class Lag {
        // // // privates:
        public string navn;
        public string adr;
        public string mail;
        public string hjemmeside;

        // // // publics:
        public Lag() {
            navn = ""; adr = ""; mail = ""; hjemmeside = "";
        }

        public void skriv() {
            Console.WriteLine("Lagnavn: {0}\nLagadresse: {1}\nLagmail: {2}\nLaghjemmeside: {3}\n", navn, adr, mail, hjemmeside);
        }

        public void les_data(string t) {
            navn = t;
            adr = les_str("Lagets adresse");
            mail = les_str("Lagets mail");
            hjemmeside = les_str("Lagets hjemmeside");
        }

        public bool har_navn(string t) {
            return (navn == t);
        }
    }
    // // // END LAG CLASS // // //

    // // // BEGIN GLOBAL 2 // // //
    // things:
    public static Person[] personer = new Person[MAXPERSONER + 1];
    public static Lag[] lag = new Lag[MAXLAG + 1];
    public static int siste_person = 0, siste_lag = 0;

    // funskjoner:
    public static void skriv_meny() {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nFØLGENDE KOMMANDOER ER LOVLIG:");
        Console.WriteLine("\tA = skriv ALT om En person");
        Console.WriteLine("\tB = skriv ALLE trenere ELLER oppmenn");
        Console.WriteLine("\tC = skriv ALT om et gitt lag");
        Console.WriteLine("\tL = nytt Lag legges inn");
        Console.WriteLine("\tP = ny Person legges inn");
        Console.WriteLine("\tQ = Quit/Avslutt");
    }

    public static char les_char(string t) {
        Console.Write(string.Concat("\n", t, ":  "));
        char retur = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()[0];
        return retur;
    }

    public static int les_int(string t, int min, int max) {
        int retur = min - 1;
        do {
            Console.Write(string.Concat("\t", t, " (", min.ToString(), "-", max.ToString(), "):  "));
            retur = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (retur < min || retur > max);
        return retur;
    }

    public static string les_str(string t) {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static funksjon les_enum() {
        char ch = '\0';
        do {
            Console.Write("\tT(rener) eller O(ppmann):  ");
            ch = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()[0];
        } while (ch != 'T' && ch != 'O');
        return ((ch == 'T') ? (funksjon)0 : (funksjon)1);
    }

    public static int finn_person(string t) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= siste_person; i++)
            if (personer[i].har_navn(t))
                return i;
        return 0;
    }

    public static int finn_lag(string t) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= siste_lag; i++)
            if (lag[i].har_navn(t))
                return i;
        return 0;
    }

    public static void skriv_person() {
        string nvn = les_str("Navn på person");
        int person_nr = finn_person(nvn);
        if (person_nr == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Personen fins ikke");
        else
            personer[person_nr].skriv();
    }

    public static void skriv_verv() {
        funksjon v = les_enum();
        for (int i = 1; i < siste_person; i++) {
            if (personer[i].har_verv(v))
                personer[i].skriv();
        }
    }

    public static void skriv_lag() {
        string lagnvn = les_str("Navn på lag");
        int lagnr = finn_lag(lagnvn);
        if (lagnr == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Laget fins ikke");
        else {
            lag[lagnr].skriv();
            for (int i = 1; i <= siste_person; i++) {
                if (personer[i].tilhorer_lag(lagnr))
                    personer[i].skriv2();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void nytt_lag() {
        if (siste_lag < MAXLAG) {
            string lagnvn = les_str("Lagets navn");
            if (finn_lag(lagnvn) == 0) {
                siste_lag++;
                lag[siste_lag] = new Lag();
                lag[siste_lag].les_data(lagnvn);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Laget fins fra før!");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Lag er full!");
    }

    public static void ny_person() {
        if (siste_person < MAXPERSONER) {
            string lagnvn = les_str("Hvilke lag tilhører personen?");
            int lagnr = finn_lag(lagnvn);
            if (lagnr != 0) {
                siste_person++;
                personer[siste_person] = new Person();
                personer[siste_person].les_data(lagnr);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Laget fins ikke!");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Personer er fulle!");
    }

    public static void skriv_til_fil() {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("personer.dta");
        for (int i = 1; i <= siste_person; i++) {
            personer[i].skriv_til_fil(file);
        }
    }

    public static void les_fra_fil() {
        string buffer;
        try {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("personer.dta");
            while ((buffer = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
                siste_person++;
                personer[siste_person] = new Person();
                personer[siste_person].les_fra_fil(file, buffer);
            }
        }
        catch {
            Console.WriteLine("Finner ikke filen!");
        }
    }
    // // // END GLOBAL 2 // // //

    // // // BEGIN MAIN // // //
    public static void Main() {
        char kommando;

        les_fra_fil();
        skriv_meny();
        kommando = les_char("Ønske");
        while (kommando != 'Q') {
            switch (kommando) {
                case 'A':
                    skriv_person(); break;
                case 'B':
                    skriv_verv(); break;
                case 'C':
                    skriv_lag(); break;
                case 'L':
                    nytt_lag(); break;
                case 'P':
                    ny_person(); break;
                default:
                    skriv_meny();
                    break;
            }
            kommando = les_char("Ønske");
        }
        skriv_til_fil();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
    // // // END MAIN // // //
}
```

Sorry for strange variable names. This is code ported from C++ assignments from my Norwegian teacher (I didn't change them 'cause I'm Norwegian as well, and I never thought I would be getting these problems)

As you can see, ALL classes defined in my code is public. So that is not my problem. The errors are generated on lines 126 and 127, as well as 160. The errors deal with the assignments of variables with my custom classes as type, and with my function returning a custom enum type. Help?

Comment: please post the code and explain clearly what you are doing and what errors you get.

Comment: How about posting some code

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging sense tells me that you're not declaring a class as public

```
public class MyType
```

IF you want to make a public field of `MyType`, it's not enough to just type `class MyType` you have to make it public explicitly.

Comment: Ow, I just had a shiver down my spine, was it you ;-)

Comment: Both of the two classes I use are public. And the main class that everyhting has to be wrapped in. Here is a url to my code on github: https://gist.github.com/jyggorath/7589742 Sorry for strange function names. I'm porting code from an assignment created by my norwegian C++ teacher.